# get short lived token via Facebook SSO

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a android / ios Facebook app which uses SSO

The client then send the access token to my serer which makes a call to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+accessToken to authenticate the user with my service (match the facebook id's)

My problem is that the access token has a 60 day expiration date. Which means the user could have logged out from the app but the access token is still valid.

What I am looking for is a access token which is only valid if the user is logged into the app / a short while after e.g. 1 hour. The reason being I am thinking of security, Facebook SSO has replaced by app username/password but I see no good way to authenticate with my server. Seems Facebook SSO is good for the client very weak for the server. There must more to the access token then this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is [revoke the login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#revokelogin) when the user logs out of your app.

**EDIT:**

From the [Facebook documentation on access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/):

> Access tokens generated via web login are short-lived tokens, but you can upgrade them to long-lived tokens. Converting short-lived tokens to long-lived tokens is covered later in this document under [Expiration and Extending Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending).
>
> Mobile apps that use Facebook's mobile SDKs get long-lived tokens.

So if you're using the SDKs, there's no way to generate a short-lived token for your app. The best thing you can do is make a call to your server to delete the stored access token when the user logs out of your app.

Comment: the issue with that is the user must authorize the application again. Makes a poor user experience. Facebook pitch SSO as a way to remove your own user auth, but I see no clean solution on the server. Seems like its designed for client side auth only

Comment: thanks. Facebook SSO is a client side only then, very weak and not suitable to replace your own usermame / password. Real shame as I know have to have two logins!

Comment: @user2859250 Why do you consider OAuth to be weak?

Comment: Its not OAuth I think is weak, is the server side verification when using SSO. If I remove my username/password I don't see how I can rely on a access token to verify the user on my server. If the access token was invalidated upon logout then that would make sense. The point is facebook sso has not server side authentication available to is pretty much useless for people who need to authenticate a user server side.

Comment: @user2859250 You shouldn't be relying on the access token alone to verify a user, especially since the access token can and will change. You should be using an immutable data point, such as the user's Facebook user ID. The approach I usually take on the server-side is this: 1. Make a call to the Facebook API to retrieve the user's graph object (this validates the token); 2. Compare the user ID from the graph object to the user ID received from the app (this validates the user ID) and then compare to user ID stored in my database to retrieve my app user.

Comment: thats what I am doing. Comparing the UID of the facebook users who registered and the one the access token returns when calling FB. If someone get holds of the users access token then I am in alot of trouble. It just seems a very weak security mechanism. Especially as the tokens are valid for 60 days. I just dont understand how facebook SSO is a replacement for a username / password

Comment: The bottom line is you can't get short-lived tokens via OAuth with Facebook. If that's an issue, either talk to Facebook or use another provider.

Comment: Any idea how I talk to Facebook, they have no forum and the support pages say post on stackoverflow

Comment: You can [report a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) or [send them a tweet](https://twitter.com/FacebookDevRel) or post something to the [developers group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers). All of which you can find from their [support page](https://developers.facebook.com/support/).